# Returning array by function

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have function, which return array:

```
Public Function BubbleSrt(ArrayIn, Ascending As Boolean)

Dim SrtTemp As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long


If Ascending = True Then
    For i = LBound(ArrayIn) To UBound(ArrayIn)
         For j = i + 1 To UBound(ArrayIn)
             If ArrayIn(i) > ArrayIn(j) Then
                 SrtTemp = ArrayIn(j)
                 ArrayIn(j) = ArrayIn(i)
                 ArrayIn(i) = SrtTemp
             End If
         Next j
     Next i
Else
    For i = LBound(ArrayIn) To UBound(ArrayIn)
         For j = i + 1 To UBound(ArrayIn)
             If ArrayIn(i) < ArrayIn(j) Then
                 SrtTemp = ArrayIn(j)
                 ArrayIn(j) = ArrayIn(i)
                 ArrayIn(i) = SrtTemp
             End If
         Next j
     Next i
End If

BubbleSrt = ArrayIn

End Function
```

I trying to assign return array to another array, using this code:

```
sequence = BubbleSrt(unsorted, True)
```

Declaration:

```
Dim unsorted(2) As Integer
Dim sequence(2) As Integer
```

Compile error - Can't assign to array. The solutions is probably very easy, but i don't know, what to do with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this one instead:

```
Dim unsorted(2) As Integer
Dim sequence() As Integer

'initializing unsorted array

sequence = BubbleSrt(unsorted, True)
```

Btw, do you know that your function `BubbleSrt` modifies your `unsorted` array? E.g. if you initialize it with values `{3,1,2}` after calling `BubbleSrt` your `unsorted` would become "sorted": `{1,2,3}`. If you don't want it, add `ByVal` in your function declaration:

```
Public Function BubbleSrt(ByVal ArrayIn, Ascending As Boolean)
```

Comment: Is there any possible to initialize sequence as global variable? Public sequence() as integer is not allowed.

Comment: `Public sequence() As Integer` works, but you should place it in the very top of the module: http://i.stack.imgur.com/qF7O2.png